# Should I capitalize Brothers?

Tags: capitalization

I am writing about the Wright Brothers.  If, later in the document, I shorten it to just "the Brothers", should I still capitalize brothers? It's seems that I should since I'm referring to a very specific pair of individuals, but it looks unusual.
Similar, but not the same as this [question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/93604/should-brother-be-capitalized-in-a-letter-salutation).

Comment: Personally, in the collocation "Wright Brothers", I would always capitalise the B - since they are well-enough understood as an entity to be accorded proper noun status. [See this article](https://www.shapell.org/historical-perspectives/between-the-lines/wright-brothers-inventing-first-successful-airplane/?gclid=Cj0KCQjwpfHzBRCiARIsAHHzyZq3MZVOwuOX9lyAInGYRBAbEX7I9ZpNRSJuDMzzfUH14LAnTxXvnHwaAhyxEALw_wcB) However when referring to "the brothers" simply as a pair of individuals I think I would leave it in lower case. But I see no harm here in maintaining the capitalisation.

Comment: @WS2 Your example plumps for 'Wright brothers' in running text. // _The 'Marx Brothers'_ must be capitalised, and I'd say that the capitalisation is still required when the abbreviated form _the 'Brothers'_ is used. (Not of course in 'Leonard, Arthur and Julius had three other brothers). _The 'Beverley Sisters'_ is rarely abbreviated, and a generic 'sisters' is more likely. I'd say _the 'Brothers'_ is unlikely for Orville and Wilbur (they're less of a 'combo'/troupe), so I'd go with generic 'brothers' when used as a single term. But I prefer the honorific _Wright Brothers_.

Comment: ... [NASA](https://wright.nasa.gov/overview.htm) seem to prefer 'the Wright Brothers' in running text, but they are perhaps in the minority. Neither form is incorrect.

Comment: The Wright Brothers team consisted of the two Wright brothers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe you should not even capitalise 'brothers' in 'Wright brothers' (with a possible exception of the title or a section header of your writing). That makes it somewhat difficult to advise on how to proceed once you've started capitalising it.

See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wright_brothers), [Encyclopaedia Britannica](https://www.britannica.com/biography/Wright-brothers), [Encyclopedia.com](https://www.encyclopedia.com/people/science-and-technology/aviation-biographies/wright-brothers), [New World Encyclopedia](https://www.newworldencyclopedia.org/entry/wright_brothers), and countless other examples. (Look in the text bodies.)

Comment: NASA seem to be on a different planet.

Comment: I think William Wycherley authored Country Wife (or Country wife?)

Comment: Also, a direct reference to the brothers at https://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org/qanda/data/faq/topics/ProperNames/faq0001.html APA also agrees, as does https://www.wright.edu/brand/editorial-style-guide#cap.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Oh Brother! Another out-of-this-world obsevation.